# How to typeset chapter heading on a page of its own with memoir

Tags: memoir, chapters

Hi I am a newbie typesetting a book with the Memoir class (texlive 2014 and LyX).

I would like to place chapter titles on a (verso) page of their own, with the text of the chapter starting on the next recto page.

In the Memoir manual I found some mention of this with an example code, but given my lack of experience I don't seem to be able to achieve the desired result.

This is a sample document:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\memendofchapterhook{%
\clearpage\m@mindentafterchapter\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Three Worlds}
Text of my chapter...

\end{document}
```

Supposedly that should start new page (`\clearpage`) after the chapter title, but it doesn't.

Can you please show me how to achieve my aim properly?

Many Thanks
Martin

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: This code works in regular LaTeX if you embed it in a simple `memoir` document.

Comment: I have updated the sample code to be a full document. It still produces the chapter title on same page with the chapter text.

Comment: @alan does my (now complete) sample document work when you try it out on your system? It is still not working for me, e.g. the chapter heading is still placed on the same page with the chapter content.